# Valores dmColor e dmDuplex da estrutura DEVMODE sempre retornando 0

Tags: c#, .net

Estou fazendo um trabalho de monitoração de impressão em C# e utilizando a API winspool. Consegui capturar grande parte dos dados que preciso, como número de páginas, documento impresso, quantidade de páginas impressas, usuário que imprimiu, etc. Utilizando a estrutura [JOB_INFO_2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/dd145020(v=vs.85).aspx).

Que contem um ponteiro para uma estrutura [DEVMODE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183565(v=vs.85).aspx) onde eu deveria conseguir informações como, numero de cópias(dmCopies), se a impressão é color ou P&B(dmColor), e se é uma impressão Duplex(dmDuplex).

Consegui acessar essa estrutura e algumas informações estão certas, por exemplo, dmCopies sempre me retorna o valor correto de quantidade de cópias enviadas para impressão, mas dmColor que deveria ser 1 para COLOR e 2 para MONOCHROME sempre me retorna 0. O mesmo acontece com dmDuplex. Deveria ser 1 para SIMPLEX, 2 para HORIZONTAL e 3 para VERTICAL.

Estou fazendo algo errado ao acessar DEVMODE?

```
public static JOB_INFO_2[] getJobsAPI(IntPtr _printerHandle)
    {

        //impressora = identificador(handle)
        var hPrinter = _printerHandle;

        /* Configurações de busca do job em EnumJobs */
        uint firstJob = 0;
        const uint noJobs = 99;
        const uint level = 2;

        // obtem o tamanho em bytes requeridos para a função 
        uint needed;
        uint returned;
        bool b1 = EnumJobsW(hPrinter, firstJob, noJobs, level, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out needed, out returned);
        uint lastError = GetLastError();

        //aloca memoria e popula as estruturas
        IntPtr pJob = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)needed);
        uint bytesCopied;
        uint structsCopied;
        bool b2 = EnumJobsW(hPrinter, firstJob, noJobs, level, pJob, needed, out bytesCopied, out structsCopied);
        var jobInfos = new JOB_INFO_2[structsCopied];
        int sizeOf = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(JOB_INFO_2));
        IntPtr pStruct = pJob;

        for (int i = 0; i < structsCopied; i++)
        {
            var jobInfo = (JOB_INFO_2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pStruct, typeof(JOB_INFO_2));
            jobInfos[i] = jobInfo;

            //acessa estrutura DEVMODE
            IntPtr pDevMode = jobInfos[i].pDevMode;
            DEVMODE devMode = (DEVMODE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pDevMode, typeof(DEVMODE));
            pStruct += sizeOf;
        }


        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pJob);
        return jobInfos;
    }
```